# Why am I getting "unknown signal 11" with this knapsack problem solver?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

### Task

Given *n* gold bars, find the maximum weight of gold that fits into bag of capacity *W*

### Input

first line contains the capacity W of the knapsack and the number *n* of bars of gold. The next line contains n integers

### Output

The max weight of gold that fits into a knapsack of capacity W.

### Constraints

1 <= W <= 10000; 1<= n <= 300; 0 <= w0, w1, w2, ... , w(n-1) <= 100000

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int optimal_weight(int W, vector<int> w) {
  int n = w.size() + 1;
  int wt = W + 1;
  int array [n][wt];
  int val = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < wt; i++) array [0][i] = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) array [i][0] = 0;

  for(int i = 1; i< n; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < wt; j++ ){
      array[i][j] = array [i-1][j];
      if (w[i-1] <= j) {
        val = array[i-1][j - w[i-1]] + w[i-1];
        if(array[i][j] < val) array[i][j] = val;
      }
    }
  }

  //printing the grid
  // for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
  //   for(int j=0; j < wt; j++) {
  //     cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
  //   }
  //   cout<<endl;
  // }
  // cout<<endl;

  return array [n-1][wt-1];
}

int main() {
  int n, W;
  std::cin >> W >> n;
  vector<int> w(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> w[i];
  }
  std::cout << optimal_weight(W, w) << '\n';
}
```

The above code works fine for smaller inputs, but gives an `unknown signal 11` error on the platform I wish to submit to. My best guess is of a possible segmentation fault, but I have been unable to debug it since quite some time now. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `int array [n][wt];` can stackoverflow when there are million elements?

Comment: You are doing a stack allocation with this statement: `int array [n][wt]`. If the stack on the plataform is small, you will get an stack overflow. Use a `std::vector` instead

Comment: VLA are not standard C++.

Comment: possibly you are filling your stack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488477/maximum-size-of-int-array Use new operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that your code doesn't work. That is, it doesn't compile when you adhere strictly to the C++ language standard, as [C++ does not support variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). (as noted by @Evg in a comment; some compilers offer this as an extension.)

The main reason for excluding those from C++ is probably why you're experiencing issues for larger problem sizes: the danger of [stack overflows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1110138/1593077), the namesake of this website  (as noted by @huseyinturgulbuyukisik in a comment). Variable-length arrays are allocated on the stack, whose size is limited. When you exceed it, you might attempt to write to a segment of memory that is not allocated to your process, triggering Linux signal 11, also known as SIGSEGV - the [segmentation violation](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/segmentation-fault-on-linux-unix.html) signal.

Instead of stack-based allocation, you should [allocate your memory on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap/80113?s=1%7C500.5298#80113). A straightforward way to do so would be using the `std::vector` container (whose default allocator does indeed allocate on the heap). Thus, you would write:

```
 std::vector<int> vec(n * wt);
```

and instead of `array[i][j]` you'd use `vec[i * wt + j]`.

Now, this is not as convenient as using `array[x][y]`; for the extra convenience you can, for example, write a helper lambda, to access individual elements, e.g.

```
auto array_element = [&vec, wt](int x, int y) { return vec[x * wt + y]; }
```

with this lambda function available, you can now write statements such as  `array_element(i,j) = array_element(i-1,j);`

or use a multi-dimensional container (`std::vector<std::vector<int>>` would work but it's ugly and wasteful IMHO; unfortunately, the standard library doesn't have a single-allocation multi-dimensional equivalent of that).

---

Other suggestions, not regarding a solution to your signal 11 issue:

- Use more descriptive variable names, e.g. `weight` instead of `wt` and `capacity` instead of `W`. I'd also consider`sub_solutions_table` or `solutions_table` instead of `array`, and might also rename `i` and `j` according to the semantics of the dynamic solution table.
- You never actually need more than 2 rows of the solutions table; why not just allocate one row for the current iteration and one row for the previous iteration, and have appropriate pointers switch between them?

Comment: @einpoklum Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
vector< vector< int> >  k(n + 1,vector< int>(W + 1));
```

with

```
int array[n][w];
```