# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my C server program (but only sometimes)?

Tags: c, networking, segmentation-fault, server

Right now, I'm trying to write a simple client/server application in order to measure the round trip time on a LAN for TCP messages of various sizes (I'm doing the timing client side). The program works fine for small packet sizes (> 1000 bytes) but I end up with a segmentation fault: 11 error for inputs of larger magnitude (10KB or greater).

```
int main() 
{ 
    struct sockaddr_in sin; 
    char buf[MAX_LINE]; 
    int len; 
    int s, new_s; 
    /* build address data structure */ 
    bzero((char *)& sin, sizeof( sin)); 
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_port = htons( SERVER_PORT);
    /* setup passive open */ 
    if (( s = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) { 
        perror("tcp program: socket"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    if (( bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)& sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0) { 
         perror("tcp program: bind"); 
         exit( 1); 
 } 
    listen(s, MAX_PENDING); 
    /* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
     while(1) { 
        socklen_t lent = (unsigned int)&len;
        if ((new_s = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)& sin, &lent)) < 0) { 
            perror("tcp program: accept"); 
            exit( 1); 
        }


        while ((len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0))){ 
            char msg[len];
            send( new_s, msg, len, 0); //echo message of same length as received message
        }
        close(new_s); 
      }      
}
```

Again, the goal was to measure RTT, so I wanted the client to send a message, the above server to receive it, then send back a message of equivalent size. I also wanted the server to continue spinning so that the client could run iteratively, sending messages of 1KB, 10KB,...1000KB, etc. However, such iterations usually result in a segmentation fault.

Oddly enough, if I configure my client to run, for example, a single 12KB message send, the server does fine, and continues to run. And if I wait a couple of seconds, I can even repeatedly call my client and the server keeps up. But if I run the single message send in rapid succession, I end up with the segfault again.

Any ideas? I apologize in advance for any elementary errors in style or format. This is my first real foray into the C language beyond "hello world".

Thanks!

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552968/is-there-any-limitation-on-the-maximum-size-of-array-in-c

Comment: Thanks a ton Merom! That actually provided the exact solution to the problem: the local declaration of char *msg resulted in insufficient memory to allocate the return message. Declaring the array outside the scope of the loop fixed this. If I could give you the credit for the answer, I would!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only part of the code that is wrong, but this is wrong:

```
while ((len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)))
```

Please read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) for `recv()`, in particular (emphasis added)...

> These calls return the number of bytes received, **or -1 if an error occurred.** The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

We know that networks are *unreliable,* and it is fairly common for `recv()` and friends to return errors.

Additionally, variable-length arrays in C are a fairly dangerous construct, because they perform dynamic allocation on the stack.  They're basically `alloca()` in disguise, and we know how dangerous `alloca()` is.  So this bit:

```
char msg[len]; // serious problems unless we have good bounds for len
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Dietrich Epp: What you said makes sense about the return value of recv(), so I modified my loop appropriately. Luckily, the bounds on len are pretty well defined by my client program, so I should be able to prep accordingly.