# How to work with POSIX C threads if you do not know their number before a runtime?

Tags: c, multithreading

I just started to get into threads in POSIX C, and I am confused how to create global array
pthread_t t[NUM_OF_THREADS] where NUM_OF_THREADS should be determined at run time. I need to create a separate thread for each category my program receives, and it can be any number of categories.

So, I do not know how many threads I should create. Basically I am calculating the number of categories in my code, and I want to create the same number of threads in my program. How would I do that?

I cannot create a global array with some variable number for NUM_OF_THREADS, meaning that NUM_OF_THREADS should be constant. I also need this array of threads to be accessible from different functions. I am stuck.

How do you work with threads if you do not know their number before runtime?

Thank you

Comment: Just don't store your `pthread_t`s into a fixed-size global array. Is the question asking for an answer more complicated than that?

Comment: Just like you work with any other data type without knowing its number before run time.

Comment: @Tommy But global data is what being shared between threads... and I need this data to be global and accessible from any part of my source code.. I am confused

Comment: Well, design your global data so that it doesn't need an array of the threads.  It's far from unusual to not bother keeping any record of the 'pthread_t's at all and to communicate with the threads in some other fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question doesn't seem to have as much to do with threading as it does a global variable. You need a pointer...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

const size_t NUM_OF_THREADS = 5;
pthread_t *my_threads = NULL;

int spawnThreads (void);

int main (void) {
   // can access my_threads;
   my_threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t *) * NUM_OF_THREADS);
   otherFunc();
   free(my_threads);
   return 0;
}

int spawnThreads (void) {
    // can access my_threads;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_THREADS ; ++i ) {
        my_threads[i] = pthread_create(...);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is same as how to use a array if you don't know the lenth before runtime.

a direct way is to use variable-length arrays, there's something matters as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965623/why-am-i-getting-a-segmentation-fault-in-my-c-server-program-but-only-sometimes) says

> variable-length arrays in C are a fairly dangerous construct, because they perform dynamic allocation on the stack. They're basically alloca() in disguise, and we know how dangerous alloca() is.

a more safe way is to malloc a block of memory at first. while i'm editing the answer, @Zak shows a example, that's a good way. Just regard my answer as an addtion ;)