# Creating large arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

My question is related to C language.
I have to create a big array of around two million elements but the computer gives a "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)" error. I am simply saying:

```
int integer_array[2000000];
float float_array[2000000];
```

I am sure this has something to do with the memory allocated to arrays but I cannot figure out the right solution.

Comment: Please give a complete code example. We should be able to compile and run it ourselves and get the same result you are asking about.

Comment: Your are allocating these array on stack and not heap.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is one of *many* duplicates to this problem: [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any limitation on the maximum size of array in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552968/is-there-any-limitation-on-the-maximum-size-of-array-in-c)

Comment: @WhozCraig Right you are sir.  Just throw that puppy in the free store and off the stack.

Comment: @i486 - oops...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen unless I see the actual encompassing function, thereby validating my assumption this is a stack issue, I can't pull the lever on closing this as a duplicate. It's likely, but the OP did *not* post a mcve that confirms it, which frankly kinda sucks =(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C programming, why does this large array declaration produce a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049934/c-programming-why-does-this-large-array-declaration-produce-a-segmentation-faul)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you need to create such an array dynamically on the heap.

```
int *integer_array = (int*)malloc(2000000 * sizeof(int));
float *float_array = (float*)malloc(2000000 * sizeof(float));
```

The array might be too large for stack allocation, e.g. if used not globally, but inside a function.

```
int main () {
    int a[200000000]; /* => SEGV */
    a[0]=0;
}
```

The easiest fix, move the array outside:

```
int a[200000000];
int main () {
    a[0]=0;
}
```

You can also declare it static:

```
int main () {
    static int a[200000000];
    a[0]=0;
}
```

Note that the stack size is system dependent. One can change it with ulimit.

Comment: All casts are bad. No need to cast the return value of malloc(). Also, a more robust alternative is to use sizeof object instead of sizeof(type). Final nit, integer_array is poorly named. It's not an array, sizeof(integer_array) will not return 2000000 * sizeof(int).

    int *integer_array = (int*)malloc(2000000 * sizeof(int));
    int *ip = malloc(2000000 * sizeof *ip) is more idiomatic in C.

Comment: @BjornA. You are talking nonsense. All of your arguments are false.

Comment: Really? I think not, but feel free to _argue_ properly. Show me where I'm wrong. But remember, the language in question is C, not C++.

Comment: I said all your arguments are false. malloc needs to be casted, this is C. sizeof(type) is superior. integer_array is properly named.
int integer_array = (int)malloc(2000000 * sizeof(int)); is nonsense.
int *ip is not the question here.

Comment: " malloc needs to be casted, this is C. "
You're a funny guy, @rurban. Or a troll, hard to tell. ;)  

Anyhow, the comments speak for themselves. TTFH

Comment: Edit: I see that lots of * (asterix) has disappeared from my first comment. That's unfortunate and may have caused some confusion.

Comment: For disputes like this I refer to the C book (k&r) to see what the creator did. On pg 142 he casts the output of malloc and uses `sizeof()` on the data type: `return (struct tnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct tnode))`.

Comment: ip is a terrible name as it doesn't mean anything by itself. The naming convention for dynamic arrays I use is ``<type> *dynArray<name>``.
Then ``int *ip`` becomes ``int *dynArrayInt``

It's really easy to write cryptic C code when you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

Define them as `static` or put outside function. Now they are automatic and get 16MB space of stack which probably is much smaller. BTW, it is better to use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Using `double` will double the amount of memory requested for the reals.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This is megabytes, not gigabytes and not a problem for today PC.