# Segfault on initialising a large vector

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming, why does this large array declaration produce a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049934/c-programming-why-does-this-large-array-declaration-produce-a-segmentation-faul)

Why does this program crash? It works fine for a max of 1e6, and works fine if I don't set every value to 0.

Doesn't the program get all of the memory allocated?

```
int main() {
    const int max = 10000000; // 1e7
    int end[max];
    unsigned int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < max; i++ )
        end[i] = 0;
}


$ gcc test.c && ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Could it be the stack size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are usually allocated on the **stack**. Stack space is limited; you are probably getting a stack overflow here. You can't allocate a very large size like that on such memory location. Your array is too big to fit in your program's stack. A better idea to allocate such size is to allocate on the heap.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *end = malloc(sizeof *end * max);

/* some stuff */

free(end);
```

The heap is many times larger than the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack size is limited by your operating system.

If you have to allocate very big values, don't use the stack but use the heap with malloc().

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is a stack size problem.

You could manually check and change your stack size with `setrlimit` and `getrlimit`

http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit

You can also do it when compiling with the `--stack` option:

```
 gcc --stack,<your size> ...
```